# Python, Loop n numbers of vars with independent ranges

Tags: python

I have a var `l`, and it contains a n number of tuples or ranges, chosen how I like, and I want to travel/loop through it in all the ranges, like this:

```
l = (range(4), range(8))
for i in l[0]:
    for j in l[1]:
        #work with i and j

l = (range(4), range(8), range(1), range(88))
for i in l[0]:
    for j in l[1]:
        for u in l[2]:
            for y in l[3]:
                #work with i, j, u and y
```

Another way:

```
l = (range(n1), range(n2), ...)
for k in Something(l):
    #where k[0] is in n1, k[1] is in n2 .....
```

The last generalization doesn't need to be in that form, it would be ideal if it can be in a `for` loop, and I really want to avoid a recursion function.

The code needs to work in Python 3 and Python 2.

Thx.

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.product()`, e.g. `itertools.product(*l)`

Comment: :O Nice, i had no idea itertools can be mixed in that way with for loop, that is exactly what i need! Thx.